# What is the distribution for various polyhedral dice all rolled at once?

Tags: distributions, dice

Take the 5 Platonic solids from a set of Dungeons&Dragons dice.  These consist of a 4-sided, 6-sided (conventional), 8-sided, 12-sided, and 20-sided dice.  All start at the number 1 and count upwards by 1 to their total.

Roll them all, and take their sum (minimum sum is 5, max is 50).  Do so multiple times.  What is the distribution?

Obviously they will tend towards the low end [Edit: this is wrong.], since there are more lower numbers than higher.  But will there be notable inflection points at each boundary of the individual die?

[Edit:  Apparently, what seemed obvious isn't.  According to one of the commentators, the average is (5+50)/2=27.5.  I wasn't expecting this for some reason.  But, now, it's so trivial I should have known already.  Perhaps there needs to be an "algebra" of probabilities or an axiom "If a algebraic transformation works for the natural numbers, it works for probability distributions."]

Comment: Do you mean what is the distribution of the sum of discrete uniforms $[1,4]+[1,6]+[1,8]+[1,12]+[1,20]$?

Comment: Yes, sorry, will edit Q.

Comment: One way to examine it is simulation. In R: `hist(rowSums(sapply(c(4, 6, 8, 12, 20), sample, 1e6, replace = TRUE)))`. It doesn't actually tend towards the low end; of the possible values from 5 to 50, the average is 27.5, and the distribution is (visually) not far from normal.

Comment: Yeah, if I had a computer where I could code it, that's what I'd do, simulate it.  But, alas, I do not.

Comment: multinomial.  its like binomial but has more than 0 or 1 as outcomes. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multinomial_distribution  I would say that as a sum, and with uneven sizes, it would be an unfair or weighted multinomial.

Comment: many gamers I know keep a d30 and a d100 around.  They also use 2x d10's and have up to 6x d6's.

Comment: @DavidRobinson:  Thank you for that (surprising to me) result.

Comment: @EngrStudent:  I understand there are different dice.  I like to stick with platonic solids.  Where do you get d100s?

Comment: My D&D set has a d10 as well as the 5 you mention  (plus a decader, which I presume you don't include)

Comment: They look nearly like spheres.  Not amazon.  https://www.thediceshoponline.com/dice/1008/GameScience-Red-D100-Dice-OOP-Limited-Stock

Comment: @Glen_b - I put a d10 in there.  My brain went D&D.  If I need to remove it, I can.

Comment: Wolfram Alpha [computes the answer exactly](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=Expand[x^5+%281-x^4%29%281-x^6%29%281-x^8%29%281-x^12%29%281-x^20%29%2F%281-x%29^5+%2F+%284*6*8*12*20%29]).    Here is the [probability generating function](http://www.wolframalpha.com/share/clip?f=d41d8cd98f00b204e9800998ecf8427er4n0c30tds), from which you can read off the distribution directly.  BTW, this question is a special case of one that is asked and thoroughly answered at http://stats.stackexchange.com/q/3614 and at http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/116792.

Comment: No one has pointed out, so I will, roll them together or in sequence it doesn't matter, the outcome of one roll will not affect the other (die number 3 wont for whatever reason go "the second roll was low, I'll go high") or something. This means you could have done an experiment yourself quite easily.... 12 people think you did your research. That hot questions list is a joke.

Comment: @gung: I really feel dumb now.  That is what I meant, and apparently didn't think that the mean is just the sum of means of the 5 uniform distributions.  I was picturing adding the graphs together, giving the false intuition of an inflected graph.  Any published text that makes this rule concrete?

Comment: @Marcos, that's ultimately the same question as answered in Glen_b's comments below ("Yes, but my point was it's too trivial to get a journal to publish it...").

Comment: This question is a simplified version of https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/116792, which has comprehensive answers.

Comment: I don't understand the edit, because the majority of answers here *do* have graphs.  What kind of graph would you like to see?

Comment: @whuber:  Nothing further.  The graphs are convincing after I understood that one can add uniform(only?) distributions together.  That is, dist(A + B) = dist(A) + dist(B).

Comment: I don't really know why I was so convinced that the distribution was unusual, except "dice are [supposed to be] random".

Answer (score 20, accepted):

I wouldn't want to do it algebraically, but you can calculate the pmf simply enough (it's just convolution, which is *really* easy in a spreadsheet).

I calculated these in a spreadsheet*:

```
i        n(i)   100 p(i)
5         1     0.0022
6         5     0.0109
7        15     0.0326
8        35     0.0760
9        69     0.1497
10      121     0.2626
11      194     0.4210
12      290     0.6293
13      409     0.8876
14      549     1.1914
15      707     1.5343
16      879     1.9076
17     1060     2.3003
18     1244     2.6997
19     1425     3.0924
20     1597     3.4657
21     1755     3.8086
22     1895     4.1124
23     2014     4.3707
24     2110     4.5790
25     2182     4.7352
26     2230     4.8394
27     2254     4.8915
28     2254     4.8915
29     2230     4.8394
30     2182     4.7352
31     2110     4.5790
32     2014     4.3707
33     1895     4.1124
34     1755     3.8086
35     1597     3.4657
36     1425     3.0924
37     1244     2.6997
38     1060     2.3003
39      879     1.9076
40      707     1.5343
41      549     1.1914
42      409     0.8876
43      290     0.6293
44      194     0.4210
45      121     0.2626
46       69     0.1497
47       35     0.0760
48       15     0.0326
49        5     0.0109
50        1     0.0022
```

Here $n(i)$ is the number of ways of getting each total $i$; $p(i)$ is the probability, where $p(i) = n(i)/46080$. The most likely outcomes happen less than 5% of the time.

The y-axis is probability expressed as a percentage.
[image]

* The method I used is similar to the procedure outlined [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/3614/how-to-easily-determine-the-results-distribution-for-multiple-dice/3625#3625), though the exact mechanics involved in setting it up change as user interface details change (that post is about 5 years old now though I updated it about a year ago). And I used a different package this time
(I did it in LibreOffice's Calc this time). Still, that's the gist of it.

Comment: Amazing, I wasn't expecting a symmetrical distribution at all. I'm not sure why my intuition was so far off.

Comment: The sum of independent symmetric random variables is also symmetric in distribution.

Comment: Nice rule.  Is that published somewhere?

Comment: I doubt something as obvious as that would be publishable in a paper, but you might find it in a book somewhere, perhaps as an exercise.

Comment: That's what I meant.  In math, such a thing would be a theorem, provable by certain axioms and their combination and stated for the record.

Comment: Yes, but my point was it's too trivial to get a journal to publish it, it would only be set as an exercise for a student. You can use the fact that the characteristic function of a random variable that's symmetric around the origin is real and even (which fact you can find it stated at the wikipedia page on the [characteristic function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Characteristic_function_%28probability_theory%29#Properties)) -- well, and I guess you need the one-to-one property of cfs vs pmfs as well, or use the dual relationship to establish that an even cf also implies a symmetric pmf ...

Comment: ... and the fact that a product of even functions is even, but it's actually obvious enough just from direct consideration of how convolution works - in a convolution of two symmetric functions (pmfs in this case), for every term in the sum of products at one end there's a corresponding term of the same size at the other end, symmetrically placed around the center.

Comment: There is a typo. It should be $p(i) = n(i)/460800$ but it will not allow me to make an edit that is less than 10 characters.

Comment: @CrockGill No, the original is correct. 4 x 6 x 8 x 12 x 20 only has a single factor of "10" in it, not two

Comment: I don't know why it was difficult for me to see the solution.  One can just add up the means of each dice.

Comment: @glen_b:  Just a point of clarification, the output is symmetrical only with respect to min-max values.  kjetil's answer below shows an asymmetrical distribution with the inclusion of 5 impossible scenarios (rolling 1, 2, 3, 4, or 5).

Comment: You seem to be confused by the extraneous 0's produced by the use of the convolution function. Look carefully at the probabilities. They are symmetric about the mean (which is halfway between the two  values with probability `0.04891493` in kjetil's output).

Answer (score 8):

So I made this code:

```
d4 <- 1:4  #the faces on a d4
d6 <- 1:6  #the faces on a d6
d8 <- 1:8  #the faces on a d8
d10 <- 1:10 #the faces on a d10 (not used)
d12 <- 1:12 #the faces on a d12
d20 <- 1:20 #the faces on a d20

N <- 2000000  #run it 2 million times
mysum <- numeric(length = N)

for (i in 1:N){
     mysum[i] <- sample(d4,1)+
                 sample(d6,1)+
                 sample(d8,1)+
                 sample(d12,1)+
                 sample(d20,1)
}

#make the plot
hist(mysum,breaks = 1000,freq = FALSE,ylim=c(0,1))
grid()
```

The result is this plot.
[image]

It is quite Gaussian looking.  I think we (again) may have demonstrated a variation on the central limit theorem.

Comment: Hmm, the lowest roll in your simulation is 6. The probability of rolling it (or any single roll, preserving die identity) is 1:4*1:6*1:8*1:10*1:12*1:20=1:460800. My procedures would demand a sample size N at least twice (perhaps 4x) this amount (like a Nyquist limit) to reveal any errors in my modeling.

Comment: My experience with Nyquist also says 4x the minimum. ... done.  If 2 million isn't enough, let me know what it should be.

Comment: @EngrStudent It is bell-shaped and symmetric but a fair way from Gaussian (the relatively large variance of the d20 makes it a fair bit shorter tailed than normal), but there is a version of the CLT that would apply if you had a lot of different dice. (Here "a lot" is handwaving; the CLT is really about what happens as $n\to\infty$; however, in finite samples we could invoke something along the lines of Berry-Esseen - or if we set it up right we could invoke that directly - which gives bounds on how far we could be from normal)

Comment: @EngrStudent:  Sweet.  Thanks for doing the simulation.  I'm accepting Glens answer as it is a more exact answer, but your simulation was definitely practical in absence of a complete model.   Glen noted the rule that I didn't know "the sum of multiple independent symmetric random variables is also symmetric."

Comment: @EngrStudent:  BTW, doesn't your result confirm CLT?

Comment: @theDoctor no, it doesn't confirm the CLT for a host of reasons

Comment: I didn't know that I didn't know "Berry-Esseen", but now I do.  I love answering next to folks like Glen_b because I learn a lot.  Now I'm going to learn what it is.  I suspect it is what CLT is in the discrete case but I will find out.

Comment: You'd need a version of the Berry Essen inequality that doesn't assume identical distributions.

Comment: Sorry for my typo in my first comment!!!  There was no d10 in my question, even though D&D uses two of them.

Answer (score 7):

I will show an approach to do this algebraically, with the aid of R.
Assume the different dice have probability distributions given by vectors
$$    \DeclareMathOperator{\P}{\mathbb{P}}    
  P(X=i)=p(i)
$$ where $X$ is the number of eyes seen on throwing the dice, and $i$ is a integer in the range $0,1,\dots,n$. So the probability of two eyes, say, is in the third vector component. Then a standard dice has distribution given by the vector $(0,1/6,1/6,1/6,1/6,1/6,1/6)$. The probability generating function (pgf) is then given by $p(t)=\sum_0^6 p(i) t^i$. Let the second dice have distribution given by the vector $q(j)$ with $j$ in range $0,1,\dots,m$. Then the distribution of the sum of eyes on two independent dice rolls given by the product of the pgf' s, $p(t)q(t)$. Writing out the product we can see it is given by the convolution of the coefficient sequences, so can be found by the R function `convolve()`. Lets test this by two throws of standard dice:

```r
p   <-  q  <-  c(0, rep(1/6, 6))
pq  <-  convolve(p, rev(q), type="open")
zapsmall(pq)
 [1] 0.00000000 0.00000000 0.02777778 0.05555556 0.08333333 0.11111111
 [7] 0.13888889 0.16666667 0.13888889 0.11111111 0.08333333 0.05555556
[13] 0.02777778
```

and you can check that that is correct (by hand calculation). Now for the real question, five dice with 4,6,8,12,20 sides. I will do the calculation assuming uniform probs for each dice. Then:

```r
p1  <-  c(0, rep(1/4, 4))
p2  <-  c(0, rep(1/6, 6))
p3  <-  c(0, rep(1/8, 8))
p4  <-  c(0, rep(1/12, 12))
p5  <-  c(0, rep(1/20, 20))
s2  <-  convolve(p1, rev(p2), type="open")
s3  <-  convolve(s2, rev(p3), type="open")
s4  <-  convolve(s3, rev(p4), type="open")
s5  <- convolve(s4, rev(p5), type="open")
sum(s5)
[1] 1
zapsmall(s5)
 [1] 0.00000000 0.00000000 0.00000000 0.00000000 0.00000000 0.00002170
 [7] 0.00010851 0.00032552 0.00075955 0.00149740 0.00262587 0.00421007
[13] 0.00629340 0.00887587 0.01191406 0.01534288 0.01907552 0.02300347
[19] 0.02699653 0.03092448 0.03465712 0.03808594 0.04112413 0.04370660
[25] 0.04578993 0.04735243 0.04839410 0.04891493 0.04891493 0.04839410
[31] 0.04735243 0.04578993 0.04370660 0.04112413 0.03808594 0.03465712
[37] 0.03092448 0.02699653 0.02300347 0.01907552 0.01534288 0.01191406
[43] 0.00887587 0.00629340 0.00421007 0.00262587 0.00149740 0.00075955
[49] 0.00032552 0.00010851 0.00002170
plot(0:50, zapsmall(s5))
```

The plot is shown below:

[image]

Now you can compare this exact solution with simulations.

Comment: Interesting -- your graph shows the distribution to be asymmetrical, because you included the 5 impossible scenarios in the beginning.

Comment: @Marcos that doesn't make the distribution asymmetrical. The rolls 5 impossible scenarios in the end, 51,52,53,54,55, have also zero probability.

Answer (score 6):

A little help to your intuition:

First, consider what happens if you add one to all the faces of one die, e.g. the d4.  So, instead of 1,2,3,4, the faces now show 2,3,4,5.

Comparing this situation to the original, it is easy to see that the total sum is now one higher than it used to be. This means that the *shape* of the distribution is unchanged, it is just moved one step to the side.

Now *subtract* the average value of each die from every side of that die.

This gives dice marked

- $-{3\over 2}$,$-{1\over 2}$,${1\over 2}$,${3\over 2}$
- $-{5\over 2}$,$-{3\over 2}$,$-{1\over 2}$,${1\over 2}$,${3\over 2}$,${5\over 2}$
- $-{7\over 2}$,$-{5\over 2}$,$-{3\over 2}$,$-{1\over 2}$,${1\over 2}$,${3\over 2}$,${5\over 2}$,${7\over 2}$

etc.

Now, the sum of these dice should still have the same shape as the original, only shifted downwards.  It should be clear that this sum is symmetrical around zero. Therefore the original distribution is also symmetrical.

Answer (score 2):

Using the `R` software I posted earlier at https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/116913/919 for solving problems like this, you can compute the solution in one line:

```
(all <- d(1,4) + d(1,6) + d(1,8) + d(1,12) + d(1,20))
```

The output gives all 46 probabilities (not shown), which can be plotted with another line:

```
plot(all, xlab="Value", yaxp=c(0,1,2), main=expression(d[4]+d[6]+d[8]+d[12]+d[20]))
```

To this plot I have added the graph of the Normal distribution with the same variance and mean (employing a continuity correction),

```
curve(pnorm(x, mean(all)-1/2, sqrt(var.die(all))), add=TRUE, col="Red")
```

[image: Figure]

If you prefer to see the probability function, here it is:

```
with(all, plot(value, prob, type="h", main="Probability Function", cex.main=1))
```

[image: Figure 2]

Clearly the Normal approximation is already good, so we may continue to use it to describe the sum of many rolls of this combination.  But if you want to see it precisely computed, you may do so.  For instance, here is the sum of four trials with its Normal approximation superimposed (no continuity correction needed),

```
with(all+all+all+all, plot(value, prob, type="h", main="Sum of Four Trials", cex.main=1))
curve(dnorm(x, mean(all)*4, sqrt(4*var.die(all))), add=TRUE, col="Red", lwd=2)
```

[image: Figure 3]

Comment: There are many times when I am reading through answers and I say to myself "this guy has great content" and I get to the end and it was @whuber who did it.  I think it might be useful to see the difference between the fitted gaussian and the discrete distribution, where they-axis is the difference in the probabilities.

Answer (score 1):

The [Central Limit Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Central_limit_theorem) answers your question. Though its details and its proof (and that Wikipedia article) are somewhat brain-bending, the gist of it is simple. Per Wikipedia, it states that

> the sum of a number of independent and identically distributed random variables with finite variances will tend to a normal distribution as the number of variables grows.

Sketch of a proof for your case:

When you say “roll all the dice at once,” each roll of all the dice is a random variable.

Your dice have finite numbers printed on them. The sum of their values therefore has finite variance.

Every time you roll all the dice, the probability distribution of the outcome is the same. (The dice don’t change between rolls.)

If you roll the dice fairly, then every time you roll them, the outcome is independent. (Previous rolls don’t affect future rolls.)

Independent? Check. Identically distributed? Check. Finite variance? Check. Therefore the sum tends toward a normal distribution.

It wouldn’t even matter if the distribution for one roll of all dice were lopsided toward the low end. I wouldn’t matter if there were cusps in that distribution. All the summing smooths it out and makes it a symmetrical gaussian. You don’t even need to do any algebra or simulation to show it! That’s the surprising insight of the CLT.

Comment: While the CLT is relevant, and as the the other posts show, the distributions is roughly gaussian looking, we're only dealing with the sum of 5 independent _non-identical_ distributions. So point 1) 5 is not really big enough to invoke a theorem that applies "at infinity". Point 2) you can't use the vanilla CLt, because the things you sums aren't iid. You need the Lyapunov CLT, I think.

Comment: You do not need the Central Limit Theorem to say that the sum of some independent random variables with distributions symmetric about their respective centres has a symmetric distribution about the sum of the centres.

Comment: @Peter: You’re missing the structure of my proof. The OP says “roll them all at once.” I am taking each roll of _all_ the dice as _one_ random variable. Those random variables do have an identical distribution. No need for Lyapunov. Also, the OP says “do so multiple times,” which I take to mean “in the limit,” so your point #1 is not valid. We aren’t just summing one roll of 5 dice here.

Comment: @Henry: The OP worried about asymmetrical distributions: “obviously they will tend towards the low end” and “will there be notable inflection points.” The CLT is what tells us that this doesn’t matter. I think it’s easier to invoke it than to prove that you don’t need it, and speaks to the heart of the OP’s question about asymmetry and cusps.

Comment: @PaulCantrell: The OP says (correctly) *"minimum sum is 5, max is 50"* and (incorrectly) *“obviously they will tend towards the low end”*.  Symmetry for each die's distribution means that the distribution of the sum is symmetric about $\frac{5+50}{2}$ and has little or nothing to do the CLT.

Comment: Indeed, and Stig’s answer works this out quite nicely. The point of the CLT is that you don’t even have to figure any of that out to know that it all tends toward a Gaussian in the end. Again, it’s easier to invoke CLT than to show it’s unnecessary.

Comment: @PaulCantrell Each roll of all the dice is the sum of five independent non-identically distributed variables. The OP is asking about the distribution of that sum. You may do many rolls of the 5 dice, but that's just sampling from the distribution under question, nobody is summing those samples.

Comment: @PaulCantrell I guess it depends on how you interpret "Do so multiple times." Do so multiple times, and them sum again (getting a single value), or do so multiple times and look at the histogram of those samples (getting multiple values). I took the latter interpretation.

Comment: Yes, my answer assumed you’re summing (or averaging) the results. If you want the discrete distribution, look to binomial coefficients.