# roll dice 400 times, what is the probability that the total number of dots is at least 1350?

Tags: probability, normal-distribution, binomial-distribution, excel, dice

I know how to solve if roll dice 2 time and the sum is 10, but by drawing table.
Therefore, with 400 times and sum is 1350, that is ridiculous.

Let's say using Excel to solve the problem.

Should I use Binomial random function **BINOM.DIST.RANGE(trials,probability_s,number_s,[number_s2])**.
But the thing is how to know probability of getting 1350 ?

I also thought about using Normal random variable function **NORMDIST(x,mean,standard_dev,cumulative)** using the data in the picture[image]

However, the answer in the textbook is bigger than 0.8

Comment: You don't have a binomial distribution in this problem. It's not relevant to this question

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think your problem is that you are mixing *variance* and *standard deviation* in the `NORM.DIST`.

You should use `=1-NORMDIST(1350,1400,SQRT(1167),TRUE)` in Excel,

or in R:

```
sims  <- 400
mu    <- 7/2
sigma <- 35/12
pnorm(1350, mean = 400 * mu, sd = sqrt(400 * sigma), lower.tail = F)
```

giving

```
[1] 0.9283825
```

Comment: +1. Note that the usual continuity correction will work noticeably better, even with these seemingly large numbers: `pnorm(1350 - 1/2, mean = 400 * mu, sd = sqrt(400 * sigma), lower.tail = F)` gives $0.930361$, in agreement to almost five significant figures with the exact value (computed as described at https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/116913/919) of $0.930347...$.  Thus the continuity correction supplies more than two more significant figures of accuracy.

Comment: @rbm: In `NORMDIST`, why have we used fourth parameter as `TRUE` though the `x` takes discrete values?

Comment: The `true` has nothing to do with discrete/continuous, it is a `cumulative` flag, i.e. specifying whether you want to calculate PDF or CDF. Consider `NORMDIST(0,0,1,FALSE)` (which equals ~0.39) and `NORMDIST(0,0,1,TRUE)` (which is exactly 0.50!).

Answer (score -2):

in Excel

```
=1-NORMDIST(1350;1400;SQRT((VAR.P(1;2;3;4;5;6)*400));1)
```