# Formula to find percentage of winning between two different numbered dice

Tags: probability, dice

Lets say I have a dice with the numbers from 1 to 10 and another one numbered from 1 to 7. I roll both dices once. Whats the chances in percentage that the 10 numbbered dice will win in terms of having a higher number. And whats the formula to calculate this percentage?

Comment: Try making a 10 x 7 table, which will have 70 cells.  Number the rows from 1 to 10, and the columns from 1 to 7.  How many of those cells are below the diagonal?  Those will be the cells for which the 10-sided die has a higher value than the 7-sided die.  Then take it from there.

Comment: Indeed, I'd probably still have started by thinking about the 10 x 7 table and how to count the pairs of values satisfying the condition (you'll discover that you're counting all the points within a trapezoid-shape) before trying to get to a  formula for a more general situation. Take care that you correctly deal with the case where both dice show the same value. An alternative approach is to consider the distribution of the differences. If you have dealt with these problems, it is not hard to write down the distribution of the difference, but to get there initially you start from the table.

Comment: Singular: die. Plural: dice. :) Welcome to CV, Flo!

Comment: Use the techniques at https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/116913/919 to approximate the answer or apply the code there to find the exact answer.  One solution is given by `sign(d(1,10) - d(1,6))`, which outputs the probabilities of losing, tieing, and winning.

Answer (score 2):

Let's define $N$ as the maximum number on the "larger" dice and $M$ as the maximum number on the "smaller" dice.  We will develop a formula for the number of combinations for which the larger dice's value is greater than the smaller dice's value; dividing that by the total number of combinations ($NM$) will give us the result.

First, note that if the roll on the larger dice $> M$, it will always be larger than the roll on the smaller dice.  This happens $M \cdot (N-M)$ times.

If the roll on the larger dice is $7$, there are six rolls on the smaller dice less than $7$; if it's $6$, there are five rolls, and so forth.  A little thought convinces us that the total number of combinations is just the sum of the integers from $1$ to $M-1$, which equals $M(M-1)/2$.

Combining everything gives us:

$$p(\cdot) = {M(N-M) + M(M-1)/2 \over MN} = {2(N-M)+(M-1) \over 2N}=1 -{M + 1\over 2N}$$

For your problem, we get $1 - 8/20 = 0.6$.  A quick piece of clear, but inefficient, R code checks this result:

```
count <- 0
for (i in 1:7) {
  for (j in 1:10) {
    if (i < j) count <- count + 1
  }
}
count / 70
[1] 0.6
```

which matches our algebraic result.