# probability of sum of 5 dice is a certain number

Tags: probability, dice

If I throw 5 dice, then the sum of numbers should be integers from 5 to 30.

How can I get the probability that the sum is n? (n = 5,6,...,30)

I used the formula:
no of ways to get 8: 5_H_2 = 6_C_2 = 15

But this holds only for small n (n = 5, 6, ...),
This is not true for n = 30, 29, 28...