# Is it appropriate use the Binomial Theorem to analyze the problem of rolling dice?

Tags: probability, distributions

In mathematics, the [multinomial theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multinomial_theorem)

> describes how to expand a power of a sum in terms of powers of the terms in that sum. It is the generalization of the binomial theorem from binomials to multinomials.

which means not each multinomial distribution is necessarily a binomial distribution, such as rolling dice.

this [post](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/3618/250190) is using the Binomial Theorem to analyze the problem of rolling dice, is it appropriate?

in other words, is rolling dice a multinomial distribution that is not a binomial distribution?

Comment: It appears that in the linked post the binomial theorem is being used only to expand a power of a sum of just two terms.

Answer (score 1):

This really depends on exactly what you are looking at.  "Rolling dice" is a specification of *an activity*, not a specification of a *numerical outcome* that constitutes a random variable having a distribution.  If you roll a set of standard six-sided dice and you look at the counts of the six possible outcomes, then (under standard assumptions), this vector of count outcomes will have a multinomial distribution.  On the other hand, if you look at the count of only one outcome, then (under standard assumptions), this value will have a binomial distribution.  There are many other distributions you could get from "rolling dice", depending on what numerical outcome you look at.

Comment: Thank you. My question comes from this [post](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/3618/250190), which I guess does "look at the counts of the six possible outcomes", which is suitable to multinomial distribution, is it?

Comment: @baojieqh Yes, you're right: but the point of the post you reference is that (in the very first step) it exploits the uniformity of the fair die distribution to reduce a (potentially complicated) multinomial calculation to a binomial calculation.  This goes well beyond the description here, which focuses on just a single outcome.

Answer (score 1):

I think your question's confusion stems from interpreting "rolling dice" as a "problem." Rolling dice is just *rolling dice*.

The binomial distribution is useful for describing the probabilities of a number of independent  events occurring $x$ times out of $n$ attempts, each with probability $p$. If "an event" is rolling some number, say "rolling a 3" or "rolling a 4 or higher", then the binomial theorem can help you understand the probabilities of such events occurring. For example: what is the probability that a fair<sup>1</sup> six-sided<sup>2</sup> die will come up '3' exactly four times if I roll the die ten times?

$$\begin{array}{rcl}
x & = &  4\\
n & = & 10\\
p & = &  \frac{1}{6}\\
P\left(X = 6|n,p\right) & = &  {10! \choose 4!\left(10-4\right)!}\left(\frac{1}{6}\right)^{4}\left(1-\frac{1}{6}\right)^{10-4}=0.054\end{array}$$

By contrast the multinomial *theorem* gives a means of calculating the number of unique ways of ordering $n$ total things across $i$ types of those things, where the number of the first type of thing is $n_{1}$, the number of the second type of thing is $n_{2}$, etc. up to $n_{i}$. For example, suppose I roll 10 six sided dice, and obtain $5,6,5,1,5,6,3,2,1,2$, I have three '5's, two 'six's, two '1's, one '3' and two '2's, and I want to know how many unique ways I could have rolled that many '5's, '6's etc.:

$$\text{Unique permutations of $n$ rolls with above $i$ values} = {10! \choose 3!\times 2! \times 2! \times 1! \times 2!} = 75,600$$

So you can see that "rolling dice" is not a "problem", or at least not until we ask specific questions about particular kinds of behavior of dice rolls, and then the binomial distribution, or multinomial theorem, or some other statistical or mathematical tool may be useful for providing answers.

<sup>1</sup> "Fair" means each side has an equal probability of coming up on a single roll.

<sup>2</sup> There are [dice with different numbers of sides](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dice#Polyhedral_dice).

Comment: Thank you so much. $10!$ comes from 10 dice. Does $3!$ comes three '5's?

Comment: @baojieqh Yes, that's right.

Comment: So, there are 75,600 ways to get the combination of (three '5's, two 'six's, two '1's, one '3', two '2's), right? Considering this particular problem (how many unique ways I could have to get such a combination), is it a Binomial or a multinomial that is not a Binomial?

Comment: "Multinomial" means "several parts," where "several" could be any whole number.  "Binomial" is the special case of two parts.  Since rolling a die is a process that has six distinct outcomes, it produces a *multinomial* (one might term it a "hexanomial") distribution: definitely not a binomial one.

Comment: @whuber And yet the binomial distribution does an admirable job of describing the probabilities of event occurrence across multiple die rolls, just as in my example, right? Dice and rolls of them are not "multinomial" or "binomial" until and unless one names specific quantities or events that may occur.

Comment: @Alexis The second comment by the OP to your question (preceding mine) names a specific event involving more than two outcomes.  I found it useful to look at the post referenced by the OP: it reveals the motivation of the question.

Comment: @whuber Ah! Missed that. It All Makes Sense Now!